# How to display data from a Loader using Toast

Tags: java, android

I've a simple Activity (`class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`)

Also I've a simple layout with a text box and a button.

Just to keep it simple, lets say I've a Loader that loads data from a `HashMap<String>` (which is already populated) and I've intialized/configured `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` appropriately.

Now I'd like to display the content of HashMap using a Toast upon clicking on the button, (which is bound to `onClickRetrieveData(){}` in `Activity`)

Any hint on how to do that?

UPDATE: I understand how to display data on Toast (once I have the data), but my question is more of the line of retrieving data from the Loader inside onClicRetrieveData().

Comment: Make some function to show Toast in the activity and call it from onClickRetrieveData()

Comment: Torris, thanks for the comment, sorry I din't make it clear what I was looking for. Please take a look at the update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell whether you're asking how to kickstart the `Loader` to get it loading or what to do when it is done.  If we assume that you mean you want to *start* loading the data when the button is clicked and calls `onClickRetrieveData()`, then you'll do something like this:

```
@Override
void onClickRetrieveData(View v) {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

Then, your implementation of the `LoaderCallbacks.onCreateLoader()` will need to actually create an instance of your `Loader`.  The framework will then kick it off and run it appropriately.  When it is done, `onLoadFinished()` will be called and you'll have your results.  From there you can do as you please: update an `Adapter`, pop up a `Toast`, etc.

Here's a primer on `Loader`s you may find helpful: http://po.st/xHoVMf